# How to upscale an Img in CSS while, maintaining the aspect ratio?

Tags: html, image, css

After googling around a bit, I found this

**HTML**

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <img src="image.png">
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divContainer{
   width :200px;
   height:200px;
   border:solid;
 }

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

This works well but it can only scale until it reaches the native resolution of the original picture and stops scaling with the div container but, I want it to go ahead and upscale beyond its native resolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `object-fit: cover;`?

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev Omg thanks! It works great now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `object-fit: contain;` to `object-fit: cover;`.

```css
.divContainer {
    width: 700px; /* Bigger than image's width. */
    height: 500px; /* Bigger than image's height. */
    border: solid;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="divContainer">
    <img src="https://dotjpg.co/YfUB.jpg"> <!-- Image Dimensions: 640px x 426px -->
<div>
```

Comment: There's one slight issue with this on my end. Everything I try to resize the browser window I get this inexplicable little gap to appear

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. It was some other part of the code. This solution is good.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. It was some other part of the code. This solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should use `auto` for the height if you want to keep the aspect ratio. Just set the width. Second, in your example because you set a height and width on the parent element, that's as much as the img can "grow." It's not stopping because of it's native size, but because of its parent's size.

Comment: Okay so the I've tried setting the parent to 100% width and a certain height, and the auto width, height for the IMG. The problem is that right now, for my image, it stops before extending to 100% of the screen width. The height is as expected.

Comment: No it should be `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. The image is going to stop when it reaches one of the parent's boundaries unless both the img and parent are the same ratio. If you want to fill the div, use `object-fit: cover` like someone said but that's going to cut off part of your image if they're not the same ratio.